# How can i disable a plugin for a mobile phone?

Tags: mobile, responsive, social-sharing

Is there a way I can not show something to mobile users? I have a floating social bar on my responsive theme, but it get in the middle of the content if I'm on my Android phone.

I don't want to use display:none, since the JS will still load. Is there a function I can use to only show the floating bar for desktops users, and not mobile ones?

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: You can parse useragent and diable activation on match...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`wp_is_mobile()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile) function to conditionally display (or block) content for mobile users.

```
<?php if (!wp_is_mobile()) : ?>

    <!-- Stuff to hide from mobile users -->

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Hmm, but with that i would show something. I want to hide something.

Comment: ...then add an `else` in there to _show_ content to non-mobile users.

Comment: @JulianFernandes Actually the exclamation mark `!` denotes `NOT` which means `if NOT mobile show x, y, z` - so if your social bar function/content were wrapped inside the above conditional statement, then it would ONLY show itself if someone is NOT on a mobile device. This method is unreliable though, compared to a CSS media query as already shown. You **could** use JS itself to verify the media/width of the device before conditionally loading/including the JS that handles the social bar but personally, to simplify the issue, I'd just minify the plugin bar JS file and use a media query.

Comment: @userabuser Thanks for the explanation! I'm not a php guy, so i did not knew about that. Helped me out a lot :)

Comment: No problem @JulianFernandes. Be sure to mark whichever answer becomes your suitable solution (when ready) so that others may benefit from this thread in the future. Any more questions just ask away and good luck!

Comment: @userabuser Done! :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Using CSS won't prevent JS from loading generally but it's more reliable than server side sniffing. Depends on project but I would go with media queries to just hide it or bring it in page's content flow.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .sticky-social {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: Guess i will hide it with CSS and show a horizontal social bar for mobile users with is_mobile. Thanks anyway :)